# Formula field in different org not not showing any value

Tags: formula-field

Please help me with this, I checked everything in the formula and the same formula field is showing in SIT org but not in UAT org. I checked the field permissions but it seems all have the access. What could be the issue? I can't figure it out.

```
IF( 
    OR(
        ISNULL(DL_Name__c), 
        ISBLANK(DL_Name__c)
    ) , 
    DL_Perpetrator__r.Person_Name__c, 
    DL_Name__c
)
```

`DL_Perpetrator__r.Person_Name__c` - this field already has the value and `DL_Name__c` is coming as blank. So ideally it should show up `DL_Perpetrator__r.Person_Name__c` value.

Please, help or suggest what  I need to check more here.

Comment: Try to display `DL_Perpetrator__r.Person_Name__c`  and `DL_Perpetrator__c` as two separate fields to debug. I suppose it should mostly drill down to access issues in two different envs.

Comment: Thanks but I am able to get  the value in DL_Perpetrator__c as well.

Comment: you know you can vastly simplify your formula to: `BLANKVALUE(DL_Name__c, DL_Perpetrator__r.Person_Name__c)`

Comment: I tried IF(ISBlank(DL_name__C),DL_Perpetrator__r.Person_Name__c,DL_Name__C) but still can't get the value. Also in another org it is working fine cant understand why it cant work in uat

Comment: How is your formula set to handle blank values? Is it leaving blanks as blanks, or converting blanks to 0? This is controlled by a set of 2 radio buttons at the bottom of the page when you create/edit the formula.

Comment: Hi Derek , Thanks  but can't see this when I click on Edit. It is an existing formula field. But it should work even if it blank or 0 because I tried it with ISBlank formula but still no hope